# Generated Android APK gives 'App not installed' error

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to install a generated APK on my phone, but it's giving me '**App not installed**' error. The app is not unsigned and everything regarding the keystore seems fine.
I also tried generating APK for a different app and then installing it on my phone and had no problems doing so, it worked immediately and gave me no errors. I also checked the permissions in Manifest file and the dependencies in gradle file, couldn't see anything wrong with that also.

The app does compile and runs when I do it via USB & Android Studio.

Does anyone know what to do? I'm probably just doing some stupid rookie mistake or something.

You can view the  project on Github [here](https://github.com/ekranac/WeatherApp).

**EDIT**: So I tried sending the apk file to a friend to see whether it's just me having this problem and that turned out to be the case. Still not quite sure why won't install on my phone, but at least others can get their hands on it :)

Comment: Did you make sure to uninstall the debug version before attempting to install the release version?

Comment: Yes, I removed the app and all its data from the phone

Comment: Try resetting app permissions (Settings > Apps > All > Menu key > Reset application permissions )

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work either

Comment: see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36705562/3578171 its probably what you are looking for.