# App not installed

Tags: android, android-manifest, apk, release

I'm having problems when i try to install my apk in release mode, if I donwload the debug file, it works ok, but if I try to install the release file, it just says me "App not installed", image:

[image: app not installed]

that is my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="PACKAGE" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ReportActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_report" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>

        <service
            android:name=".Services.PositioningService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </service>

        <receiver
            android:name=".Receiver.PositioningBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
        </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I had already checked this link, but it didn't work!
[App Not Installed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741020/app-not-installed-error)
Thank you folks!

Comment: Check whether you have application with same package name already installed in your device.Two applications with same package name cannot exist in device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you installed debug build in your mobile.. then you need to uninstall it and install signed build.

If it still not installed then your Application related data might be still there in your memory.. ex) if you created any DB from your Application then you need to delete that from memory and try to install your signed build again.

If it still not installed and if you are using lollipop devices.. your Application might be installed in other users account too.. you to switch to other users and go to Settings->Apps->your_application and uninstall it.
even check Guest user. your application might be hiding in that too..

I had this issue.. just follow these steps.. then your application can be installed.. :)

Comment: Yep, silly me, had another instance of the app w a different name but with same identifier.

Answer (score 6):

I had also same issue when I try to install release build from playstore.

**Solution:**
The reason for  the issues is that I did not increment the **versionCode** in build.gradle of module before uploading the release build to playstore.

Answer (score 3):

If it's Android 9 just try to disabling Google Play Protect. In my case it was when I uninstall some version of App and tried to install new one. I've got  the error 'App not installed'.

Open **Play Store** -> Menu button (right top button) -> Disable the options **Scan device for security threats**

Answer (score 2):

First of all open Build-Variants window (left-bottom corner), you can see modules that are part of your app in a two column(named as module and build variants) table, change all modules build variants to release, then in your build.gradle file change minifyEnabled from true to false:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

now try to sign your apk with a valid release key, if your device already has an apk installed with different key or its debug version, uninstall it and install your release version (when users attempt to update your app it wont be a problem, because you certainly will upload a release version in market with same key as before).

Comment: I want to minify the build, I cant set false to minifyEnabled

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was not working because I was trying to install apk file, over an .aab package file.

The update between a version installed from the store released in aab, was not possibile to be updated to the apk file.

In the same time, building an apk file from the master branch, and then updating it to apk works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For this, You have to clear the data of Application Installer or Package installer. It is also caused by when an app is unknown to trust the service of com.android.packageinstaller.user.AppInstallSecurity, disable this too!, Your android also is corrupted or has been unauthorized by version, Update to 12 to prevent this error.

Answer (score 0):

in your build.gradle app module , set  minifyEnabled to false. the minify may obfuscate your code making it not so usable.
like so

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        //debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false // specify minify enabled to false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
 
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be many causes. For better troubleshooting, you should install the APK with your computer using this command:

```
adb install your-app.apk
```

Then you'd get more detailed error messages you can google.