# XAMARIN / Android App installation problem

Tags: android, .net, sqlite, xamarin, apk

I have a ready XAMARIN/Android App. When i export an APK file and install it on mobile phone the first time, there is no problem. The second time comes error "app not installed". The first time the system asks for permission to install, the second time not.

Comment: Please try the solution in this thread: [app-not-installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960863/app-not-installed)

Answer (score 0):

When you install the second time, have you uninstalled the previous version before ?

If not, you need to increment the build number and the version number of your APK before installing, so the system know it's an update.

If you do not increment the build and version number, you will need to uninstall the app before reinstalling it.

You can also try to install it via adb :

- Plug your phone in USB and enable USB debugging
- Then in a shell do : `adb install <path to apk>`

Comment: thx. I uninstall the app before reinstalling, but it doesn't help. if I increment the version it s no problem, then the installation is without error. I have to roll out the app now and my customers schould can uninstall and install the app.

Comment: @Viventum I am not sure to understand your English sorry. Did increment the build&version number work ? How to you roll out your app ? Via the PlayStore or a manual installation of the .apk ?

Comment: i roll out my app manually (download from a webserver). Increment the build number work. But uninstall and reinstall the same version number doesn't work.