# APK generated using Android Studio is not getting installed on certain devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I generated an `apk` with Android Studio without problem, but when I try to Install in my phone android v4.4.2 this error show me "
the app was not installed"

I don't understand, this is the configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ejemplogpsmaps"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
}
```

then I tried to install on another phone, Samsung Galaxy s4 android v5.0.1 and the same error was displayed

Comment: Are you installing your `apk` via USB? And if so, is installing via USB enabled on your phones?

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32960863/app-not-installed

Comment: Shankha057, I Generated APK Release.

Comment: I installed the app in version 9 and 7, and this work.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the app been installed via USB.
then check if the flavour is release and not debug. if it's in debug then try building another one with the release version selected

Answer (score 0):

Android Jelly Bean 4.2.x is actually [API level](https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers) 17, which has to be declared accordingly:

```
minSdkVersion 17
```

And also, the Google Play Services plugin is missing:

```
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Comment: my phone is 4.4.2